# Javascript prod and dev differentiation in the frontend with Express and HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For my web app, I am using Express, Node.js in the backend, and in the front-end I am serving some HTML files. I am not using any front-end framework.

In the backend, I am specifying the front-end files' location with:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../public")));
```

In the `public` folders, I am placing all the front-end HTML files. I also have some Express routers to serve users the correct files:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/html/main/example.html"));
});
```

In `example.html` file, it is requiring a JS file `<script src="/resource/js/script1" async></script>` Inside `script1`, I am using a public key `pk_test_wefwefeweffwe`. That key is only for development. For production, I need a new key `pk_live_woefiweoifnweoif`. For now, whenever we deploy live. I have to change that key manually. I am wondering if there is an automatic way of doing it.

In the node.js backend, I can detect whether we are in production or development with `process.env.NODE_ENV`. But that is not possible to detect in a front-end JS file such as `script1`. I thought of serving different HTML files depending if the backend environment is prod or dev, but that seems a little tedious, since I have to update the HTML/JS file every time I make a change.

Is there a convenient method of making/serving different front-end files (or modifying a part of the front-end file depending if the environment is prod or dev) depending if the environment is prod or dev?

Comment: I feel like the easiest way would be for `script1` to be able to tell what environment it's in. I know you mentioned this is not possible, but I feel like there has to be some way (even if it's just taking a peek at the URL). If that's really not possible, what does your app deployment look like? If you have any kind of automation, it could inject the correct variable during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

### Compile time

If you're running a build for your UI you can replace environment variables at compilation time (Webpack and Rollup and all others should have the ability).

Advantages: No special system to read env vars. Can do compile time differences for different envs (e.g. source maps or dev builds with more debugging for dev env). No server required to dynamically insert the right env vars.

Disadvantages: Can significantly complicate deployment pipelines particularly needing to create Docker images for each env rather than promoting a single one through.

### Run time

You pass your env vars by either manipulating the served HTML in `<head>`:

```
<script>
  window.__ENV = { someEnvVars: 'nice' }
</script>
```

Or by adding to your HTML `<head>` in the front end files:

```
<script src="envvars.js"></script>
```

And then detect if this file is being requested on the NodeJS server and return `window.__ENV = { someEnvVars: 'nice' }` as the content dynamically.

Advantages: Simple deploy pipeline in professional Docker type situations. No need for special front end build tools to replace variables.

Disadvantages: Requires a server to dynamically insert the env vars (your app is less portable and can't simply be run on any server which can serve static files). Have to make one production worthy build (NODE_ENV = 'production') for all envs (less debugging output in React for example).